# Unable to find .mongorc.js file under home directory

Tags: mongodb

The documentation says this file is here

```
/etc/mongorc.js
```

Some other resources say that this file is under home directory.

I was not able to find this file in both places. Please help!

**Note** that my OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files beginning with `.` are hidden files. If you are viewing nautilus, in home folder:

```
ctrl+h
```

will show you the hiddenfiles.

If you are viewing in command line, try in home folder

```
ls -a | less
```

or

```
ls .mon*
```

If there is no file, you can create it in the home folder and start using it with the name `.mongorc.js` in the home folder.

Comment: no...there is no such file even among hidden ones :(